# Vue 3 Rendering array array of vnodes in setup()

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am looking in the setup function to render an array of buttons. For simplicity purposes I have provided this example below.

When I use an array and push or assign values as default, then place the array with in the render function I do not see any reactivity on click.

```js
setup(props, {emit, slots}) {
    const base_number = ref(1)

    const base_offset= computed(()=> { return base.value + 2 })
    let buttons = [base_offset.value]

    let pageClick =  (event , pageNumber ) => {
       base_number.value = 3
    }

    return  h("ul",{ class: "pagination", 'onClick' : event => { pageClick(event, 1)}},
               buttons
            )
```

However when I place the array of components like so in the return , reactivity and value updating works.

```js
   //On click will update  base_offset
    return  h("ul",{ class: "pagination", 'onClick' : event => { pageClick(event, 1)}},
                      [base_offset.value]
             )

}
```

What am I missing and is it possible to pass in a array of vnodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of returning the `VNode` array directly from `setup()`, it should return a *render function* that returns a `VNode` array (and you should see a browser console warning regarding this):

```js
export default {
  setup() {
    // return h(...) ❌
    return () => h(...) ✅
  }
}
```

Within that render function, create the `buttons` array of `VNodes`. Note that `VNode`s created outside of the render function are not reactive.

```js
export default {
  setup() {
    //...

    // ❌ non-reactive buttons array
    // let buttons = [base_offset.value, base_offset.value + 2, base_offset.value + 4]

    return () => {
      // ✅ reactive buttons array
      let buttons = [base_offset.value, base_offset.value + 2, base_offset.value + 4]

      return h(
        'ul',
        {
          class: 'pagination',
          onClick: (event) => {
            pageClick(event, 1)
          },
        },
        buttons
      )
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vnode-array-of-reactive-refs?file=src/components/MyComponent.js)